# Как отсортировать GridSearchCV.cv_results_

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Прохожу курс по data science и там используют библиотеку sklearn , где есть метод GridSearchCV, проблема в том , что изменили функцию grid_scores на cv_results_ , при функции grid_scores , всё работало без ошибок и выдавало ответ , как только я ввёл место cv_results_ то в `lambda x: -x.mean_validation_score` выходит ошибка :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-f6684c16a004> in <module>
----> 1 sorted(gridsearch.cv_results_,key = lambda x: -x.mean_validation_score)

<ipython-input-184-f6684c16a004> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 sorted(gridsearch.cv_results_,key = lambda x: -x.mean_validation_score)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'
```

Я не могу понять почему считает строковым значения , хотя всё  в числовых значения. 
Вот код :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

cs = 10**np.linspace(-3,1,5)
cs

grid = {'C': cs}
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)

%%time
gridsearch.fit(X_train_fin, y_train_fin)

sorted(gridsearch.cv_results_,key = lambda x: -x.mean_validation_score)
```

В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), `cv_results_` возвращает `словарь` в котором есть нужный вам ключ `mean_validation_score`. Поэтому попробуйте сделать, как предложил @MaxU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Удобнее всего создать Pandas DataFrame из результатов `gridsearch.cv_results_`.

Пример:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=123)

cs = 10**np.linspace(-3,1,5)
grid = {'C': cs, 'max_iter': [100, 200, 500]}
gs = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5, n_jobs=-1)

gs.fit(X_train, y_train)


res = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        "mean_test_score": gs.cv_results_["mean_test_score"],
        "mean_fit_time": gs.cv_results_["mean_fit_time"]})
      .join(pd.io.json.json_normalize(gs.cv_results_["params"]).add_prefix("param_"))
)
```

---

```
In [49]: res
Out[49]:
    mean_test_score  mean_fit_time  param_C  param_max_iter
0          0.325000       0.009396    0.001             100
1          0.325000       0.009995    0.001             200
2          0.325000       0.004998    0.001             500
3          0.666667       0.004398    0.010             100
4          0.666667       0.004598    0.010             200
5          0.666667       0.003398    0.010             500
6          0.916667       0.003998    0.100             100
7          0.916667       0.002999    0.100             200
8          0.916667       0.004398    0.100             500
9          0.950000       0.010595    1.000             100
10         0.950000       0.013793    1.000             200
11         0.950000       0.011300    1.000             500
12         0.958333       0.011194   10.000             100
13         0.958333       0.011394   10.000             200
14         0.958333       0.015193   10.000             500

In [50]: res.nlargest(5, "mean_test_score")
Out[50]:
    mean_test_score  mean_fit_time  param_C  param_max_iter
12         0.958333       0.011194     10.0             100
13         0.958333       0.011394     10.0             200
14         0.958333       0.015193     10.0             500
9          0.950000       0.010595      1.0             100
10         0.950000       0.013793      1.0             200
```

---

Набор лучших гиперпараметров:

```
In [51]: gs.best_params_
Out[51]: {'C': 10.0, 'max_iter': 100}
```

Лучшая точность (для гиперпараметров указанных выше):

```
In [52]: gs.best_score_
Out[52]: 0.9583333333333334
```

Индекс лучшего элемента в `cv_results_`:

```
In [53]: gs.best_index_
Out[53]: 12
```

Лучший "estimator" - его можно вызывать для предсказаний:

```
In [54]: gs.best_estimator_
Out[54]:
LogisticRegression(C=10.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn',
          n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn',
          tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: такой вопрос как теперь из этого датасета взять  лучший показатель , с помощью функции best_params_

Comment: Я вводил gridsearch.best_params_ 
и получал  словарь 
{"C":10.0}

Comment: @АнастасСмех, вот вы и получили лучший набор гиперпараметров... Не понимаю тогда суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
results = pd.DataFrame(xgb_grid.cv_results_)
display(results.sort_values(by='rank_test_score').head(5))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
%%time
cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
pipe = Pipeline([('regresion', RandomForestRegressor())])

param_grid =[
{'regresion': [RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42, n_jobs =-1)],
 'regresion__n_estimators': [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 10, stop = 20, num = 5)],
 'regresion__max_depth': [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 11, stop = 15, num = 5)] ,
 'regresion__max_features': [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 15, stop = 17, num = 3)] 
},

{'regresion': [GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)],
 'regresion__max_features':[6,7,8,9],
 'regresion__max_depth': [4, 5, 6]
}
```

]

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=cv, return_train_score=True)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

print("----------------- Обучили и тестировали -------------------")
print("Наилучшие параметры:\n{}\n".format(grid.best_params_))
print("Средняя правильность для наилучшей модели кроссвалидации на 
валидационных тестовых наборах: {:.6f}\n".format(grid.best_score_))  
print("Средняя правильность для наилучшей модели на тестовом наборе: 
{:.6f}\n".format(grid.score(X_test, y_test)))
gridresults = pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)
display(gridresults.sort_values(["rank_test_score"]).T)


train_acc = []
test_acc = []
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop =10, num = 5)]

for i in tqdm(max_depth):
  gb = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators =1000, random_state=42, max_depth=i) 
  gb.fit(X_train, y_train)

  train_acc.append(gb.score(X_train, y_train))
 test_acc.append(gb.score(X_test, y_test))

 train_acc, test_acc  = np.asarray(train_acc), np.asarray(test_acc)
 print("Best accuracy is {:.4f}% with {} max_depth".format(max(test_acc), 
                                                    
 max_depth[np.argmax(test_acc)]))


 plt.style.use('ggplot')
 %matplotlib inline
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
 ax.plot(max_depth, train_acc, alpha=0.5, color='blue', label='train')
 ax.plot(max_depth, test_acc, alpha=0.5, color='red', label='cv')
 ax.legend(loc='best')
 ax.set_ylim([0.85,1.02])
 ax.set_ylabel("Accuracy")
 ax.set_xlabel("max_depth")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]